# When does an elliptic curve have accumulation points?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

If the rank of an elliptic curve is greater than 1,then it has infinitely many rational points,I wonder how are these rational points distributed, especially, can we find an elliptic curve such that there are infinitely many  rational points when $x\in (0,1)$?

Comment: As the rank is positive, the rational points are dense in their connected components as curve over $\mathbb{R}$, so they are all accumulation points, see [this paper](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/zls002/papers/rationalpoints.pdf).

Comment: @Mercury Many thanks!

Comment: @Mercury do you have a current link? The link in your previous comment doesn't work.

Comment: @ArthurVause [The Real Topology of Rational Points on Elliptic Curves](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~zscherr/papers/rationalpoints.pdf)

Comment: @Mercury Thanks.